# Is there a way to always send some data to the render engine?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm running express.js with jade. Now I realize that I need to send a user object to jade every time:

```
var renderObject = {
    navigation: [{
        url: "/",
        title: "Home"
    }],
    user: user
}
res.render('MyTemplate', renderObject);
```

However, I'm rather deep into the project and have a lot of routes where res.render is called. So now, lazy as I am, I started to look if there's a way to jack in to the renderer before the renderer is actually called.

Pseudocode:

```
 app.beforeRendering(function(template,renderObject,next) {
      renderObject.user = GLOBAL.myUserObject;
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set properties on `res.locals` to be included in all renders:

```
res.locals.nav = [{
  url: "/",
  title: "Home"
}];
res.locals.user = user;
```

Or perhaps replace the whole object in one step:

```
res.locals = {
  navigation: [{
    url: "/",
    title: "Home"
  }],
  user: user
};
```